# mongose.connect(. . .) is not a function

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database using the mongoose NPM module. But whenever I try the connect function, I get `mongoose.connect(...) is not a function`

I don't believe this has to do anything with my code, so, I'm guessing it's a problem related to the module. Not sure though.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so.

Just to clarify, I had the wrong MongoDB URI when trying to connect. So, that's what caused the issue. No help is needed, thanks.